# RoR script/plugin install option " -r " .. what does it do ... possibly a Git specification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

So I'm running these commands to install a particular version of rspec

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec.git -r 'refs/tags/1.2.9'
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails.git -r 'refs/tags/1.2.9'
```

What does the "-r" option do?  ( before the 'refs/tags/1.2.9' in each command )

Is this a git option? or an option on the ruby/ror install?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, using the `-r` parameter simply allows you to specify which branch of the git repository you want to install, instead of the current master branch.

It is an install parameter, not a git parameter.